# Calling a function in a class failure

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I have a problem. I am trying to build an artificial intelligence game and I am encountering a problem. I copied a player and made an inheritance to the previous one (class Player(SelectiveAlphaBeta.Player)). For now the search in the game tree which I am making is the same (it only print maximum and minimum scores of each level – just for helping me choosing a right threshold). However it crashes in:

```
class Player(SelectiveAlphaBeta.Player):
def __init__(self, setup_time, player_color, time_per_k_turns, k):
    SelectiveAlphaBeta.Player.__init__(self, setup_time, player_color, time_per_k_turns, k, 0.25)  # TODO: w

def get_move(self, board_state, possible_moves):
    self.clock = time.process_time()
    self.time_for_current_move = self.time_remaining_in_round / self.turns_remaining_in_round - 0.05
    if len(possible_moves) == 1:
        return possible_moves[0]

    current_depth = 1
    prev_alpha = -INFINITY

    # Choosing an arbitrary move:
    best_move = possible_moves[0]

    if (self.w < 1):
        minimax = MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruningWithWDeepeningUntilRestfulness
        (self.utility, self.color, self.no_more_time, self.w)
    else:  # self.w == 1
        minimax = MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruning(self.utility, self.color, self.no_more_time)
    time_last_move = 0;
    print('debugger - line 1')

    # Iterative deepening until the time runs out.
    while True:
        print('{} going to depth: {}, remaining time: {}, prev_alpha: {}, best_move: {}'.format(
            self.__repr__(), current_depth, self.time_for_current_move - (time.process_time() - self.clock),
            prev_alpha, best_move))

        time_before = time.process_time()
        time_left = self.time_for_current_move - (time.process_time() - self.clock);
        # if (time_last_move <= time_left):
        try:
            print('debugger - line 2')
            (alpha, move), run_time = run_with_limited_time(
                minimax.search, (board_state, current_depth, -INFINITY, INFINITY, True), {},
                time_left)
            print('debugger - line 3')
        except (ExceededTimeError):
            print('no more time')
            break
        except (MemoryError):
            print('no more memory')
            break
        # else:
        #    print('{} has no enough time ({}) left to go deeper'.format(self.__repr__(), time_left))
        #    break;

        time_after = time.process_time()
        time_last_move = time_after - time_before

        if self.no_more_time():
            print('no more time')
            break

        prev_alpha = alpha
        best_move = move

        if alpha == INFINITY:
            print('the move: {} will guarantee victory.'.format(best_move))
            break

        if alpha == -INFINITY:
            print('all is lost')
            break

        current_depth += 1

    if self.turns_remaining_in_round == 1:
        self.turns_remaining_in_round = self.k
        self.time_remaining_in_round = self.time_per_k_turns
    else:
        self.turns_remaining_in_round -= 1
        self.time_remaining_in_round -= (time.process_time() - self.clock)
    return best_move

def utility(self, state):
    return SelectiveAlphaBeta.Player.utility(self, state)

def no_more_time(self):
    return SelectiveAlphaBeta.Player.no_more_time(self)

def __repr__(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(abstract.AbstractPlayer.__repr__(self), 'SelectiveAlphaBetaWithRestfulness{}'.format(str(self.w)))
```

nothing is missing because this the signature of the function:

```
class MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruningWithW(MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruning):
def __init__(self, utility, my_color, no_more_time, w):
    MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruning.__init__(self, utility, my_color, no_more_time)
    self.w = w

def search(self, state, depth, alpha, beta, maximizing_player):
    """Start the MiniMax algorithm.

    :param state: The state to start from.
    :param depth: The maximum allowed depth for the algorithm.
    :param alpha: The alpha of the alpha-beta pruning.
    :param alpha: The beta of the alpha-beta pruning.
    :param maximizing_player: Whether this is a max node (True) or a min node (False).
    :return: A tuple: (The alpha-beta algorithm value, The move in case of max node or None in min mode)
    """

    if depth == 0 or self.no_more_time():
        return self.utility(state), None

    next_moves = state.legalMoves()
    if not next_moves:
        # This player has no moves. So the previous player is the winner.
        return INFINITY if state.currPlayer != self.my_color else -INFINITY, None

    list = []
    for next_move in next_moves:
        if (self.no_more_time()):
            del list[:]
            return self.utility(state), None
        new_state = copy.deepcopy(state)
        new_state.doMove(next_move)
        list.append((new_state, next_move, self.utility(new_state)))

    list.sort(key=itemgetter(2))
    if (self.no_more_time()):
        del list[:]
        return self.utility(state), None

    if maximizing_player:
        selected_move = next_moves[0]
        best_move_utility = -INFINITY
        for i in range(int(len(list)) - 1, int(len(list)) - int(len(list) * self.w) - 1, -1):
            minimax_value, _ = self.search(list[i][0], depth - 1, alpha, beta, False)
            alpha = max(alpha, minimax_value)
            if minimax_value > best_move_utility:
                best_move_utility = minimax_value
                selected_move = list[i][1]
            if beta <= alpha or self.no_more_time():
                break
        del list[:]
        return alpha, selected_move

    else:
        for i in range(0, int(len(list) * self.w)):
            beta = min(beta, self.search(list[i][0], depth - 1, alpha, beta, True)[0])
            if beta <= alpha or self.no_more_time():
                break
        del list[:]
        return beta, None

class MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruningWithWDeepeningUntilRestfulness(MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruning):
def __init__(self, utility, my_color, no_more_time, w):
    MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruningWithW.__init__(self, utility, my_color, no_more_time, w)
    # self.treshold_restfulness = TODO

def search(self, state, depth, alpha, beta, maximizing_player):
    """Start the MiniMax algorithm.

    :param state: The state to start from.
    :param depth: The maximum allowed depth for the algorithm.
    :param alpha: The alpha of the alpha-beta pruning.
    :param alpha: The beta of the alpha-beta pruning.
    :param maximizing_player: Whether this is a max node (True) or a min node (False).
    :return: A tuple: (The alpha-beta algorithm value, The move in case of max node or None in min mode)
    """

    print('debugger - line 4')

    if depth == 0 or self.no_more_time():
        return self.utility(state), None

    next_moves = state.legalMoves()
    if not next_moves:
        # This player has no moves. So the previous player is the winner.
        return INFINITY if state.currPlayer != self.my_color else -INFINITY, None

    list = []
    for next_move in next_moves:
        if (self.no_more_time()):
            del list[:]
            return self.utility(state), None
        new_state = copy.deepcopy(state)
        new_state.doMove(next_move)
        list.append((new_state, next_move, self.utility(new_state)))

    list.sort(key=itemgetter(2))
    if (self.no_more_time()):
        del list[:]
        return self.utility(state), None

    if maximizing_player:
        selected_move = next_moves[0]
        best_move_utility = -INFINITY
        for i in range(int(len(list)) - 1, int(len(list)) - int(len(list) * self.w) - 1, -1):
            minimax_value, _ = self.search(list[i][0], depth - 1, alpha, beta, False)
            alpha = max(alpha, minimax_value)
            if minimax_value > best_move_utility:
                best_move_utility = minimax_value
                selected_move = list[i][1]
            if beta <= alpha or self.no_more_time():
                break
        print('Utility of best Move in deepening in depth of {} is {}'.format(depth, minimax_value))
        del list[:]
        return alpha, selected_move

    else:
        for i in range(0, int(len(list) * self.w)):
            beta = min(beta, self.search(list[i][0], depth - 1, alpha, beta, True)[0])
            if beta <= alpha or self.no_more_time():
                break
        del list[:]
        return beta, None
```

The error message is:

```
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 921, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 869, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Eli\workspace\HW2\amazons\utils.py", line 36, in function_wrapper
result = func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'maximizing_player'
```

for convenience the original player:

```
class Player(players.simple_player.Player):
def __init__(self, setup_time, player_color, time_per_k_turns, k, w):
    players.simple_player.Player.__init__(self, setup_time, player_color, time_per_k_turns, k)
    self.w = w;

def get_move(self, board_state, possible_moves):
    self.clock = time.process_time()
    self.time_for_current_move = self.time_remaining_in_round / self.turns_remaining_in_round - 0.05
    if len(possible_moves) == 1:
        return possible_moves[0]

    current_depth = 1
    prev_alpha = -INFINITY

    # Choosing an arbitrary move:
    best_move = possible_moves[0]

    if (self.w < 1):
        minimax = MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruningWithW(self.utility, self.color, self.no_more_time, self.w)
    else:  # self.w == 1
        minimax = MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruning(self.utility, self.color, self.no_more_time)
    time_last_move = 0;

    # Iterative deepening until the time runs out.
    while True:
        print('{} going to depth: {}, remaining time: {}, prev_alpha: {}, best_move: {}'.format(
            self.__repr__(), current_depth, self.time_for_current_move - (time.process_time() - self.clock),
            prev_alpha, best_move))

        time_before = time.process_time()
        time_left = self.time_for_current_move - (time.process_time() - self.clock);
        # if (time_last_move <= time_left):
        try:
            (alpha, move), run_time = run_with_limited_time(
                minimax.search, (board_state, current_depth, -INFINITY, INFINITY, True), {},
                time_left)
        except (ExceededTimeError):
            print('no more time')
            break
        except (MemoryError):
            print('no more memory')
            break
        # else:
        #    print('{} has no enough time ({}) left to go deeper'.format(self.__repr__(), time_left))
        #    break;

        time_after = time.process_time()
        time_last_move = time_after - time_before

        if self.no_more_time():
            print('no more time')
            break

        prev_alpha = alpha
        best_move = move

        if alpha == INFINITY:
            print('the move: {} will guarantee victory.'.format(best_move))
            break

        if alpha == -INFINITY:
            print('all is lost')
            break

        current_depth += 1

    if self.turns_remaining_in_round == 1:
        self.turns_remaining_in_round = self.k
        self.time_remaining_in_round = self.time_per_k_turns
    else:
        self.turns_remaining_in_round -= 1
        self.time_remaining_in_round -= (time.process_time() - self.clock)
    return best_move
```

and for convenience - run_with_limited_time:

```
def run_with_limited_time(func, args, kwargs, time_limit):
"""Runs a function with time limit

:param func: The function to run.
:param args: The functions args, given as tuple.
:param kwargs: The functions keywords, given as dict.
:param time_limit: The time limit in seconds (can be float).
:return: A tuple: The function's return value unchanged, and the running time for the function.
:raises PlayerExceededTimeError: If player exceeded its given time.
"""
q = Queue()
t = Thread(target=function_wrapper, args=(func, args, kwargs, q))
t.start()

# This is just for limiting the runtime of the other thread, so we stop eventually.
# It doesn't really measure the runtime.
t.join(time_limit)

if t.is_alive():
    raise ExceededTimeError

q_get = q.get()
if isinstance(q_get, MemoryError):
    raise q_get
return q_get
```

There is of course no mention to the object only to the functions of the games which run it. I don't know why it is happening. It must be very stupid but I have no idea… I had done only a simple copy of the code and I haven't changed this line…

Thanks in advance, 
Eli

Comment: Show your (whole) code. Change the title. Rewrite your question (the way you're writing is weird and confusing)

Comment: What is signature of `run_with_limited_time`?

Comment: Definitely rewrite your title.

Comment: What are `minimax` and how is `run_with_limited_time` implemented ?

Comment: what title would you advise?

Comment: minimax is the value of minimax algorithm. Minimax algorithm in AI is an algorithms which helps to play game. When you have a game tree you first choose your maximum option in your turn (you will make the best move) and your opponent in his turn would choose his best move (the minimum value for you)

Comment: where can be found the source code for "amazons/utils.py" ?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
    minimax = MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruningWithWDeepeningUntilRestfulness
    (self.utility, self.color, self.no_more_time, self.w)
```

These are actually two separate lines, the second of which does nothing, while you intended it to be a single expression. It will assign `minimax` to be the class itself instead of an instance, which causes problems when calling a method on the class later.

You can put everything on one line, or just move the opening parenthesis to the first line (as Python allows expressions to continue on the next line when parentheses are left open):

```
minimax = MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruningWithWDeepeningUntilRestfulness(
    self.utility, self.color, self.no_more_time, self.w)
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot!